# Can't get phone number to autofill on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

The `<TextInput>` component has a `textContentType` field which allows you to autofill certain fields, i.e. name, email, phone, etc. I can't seem to get it to autofill the phone number, am I missing anything?

```
<TextInput
    autoFocus
    blurOnSubmit={false}
    editable={!loading}
    placeholder="Enter phone number"
    textContentType="telephoneNumber"
    dataDetectorTypes="phoneNumber"
    maxLength={100}
    keyboardType="phone-pad"
    value={phone}
/>
```

RN version is 0.55

Comment: UPDATE: Updating RN to latest fixed it

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on an emulator on a Mac the keyword won't show up, but how you have it it's ok. Try running it up on a real device!

Check this snack out: [@abranhe/stackoverflow-56691969](https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/stackoverflow-56691969)

[image]

The source code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  state: {
    phone: '',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          autoFocus
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          placeholder="Enter phone number"
          textContentType="telephoneNumber"
          dataDetectorTypes="phoneNumber"
          maxLength={100}
          keyboardType="phone-pad"
          onChangeText={phone => this.setState({ phone })}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 50,
  },
});
```

Comment: That's the weird part, I am running it on a real device (OS 12.3.1)

Comment: Update: It was fixed by updating RN

Comment: @lifwanian what react native version were you on and to what version did you update? I'm having the same issue on RN 61